# How do I find out what computers I have authorized?

Tags: itunes

I just authorized iTunes against a laptop and I was expecting it to be my third of five computers authorized on my iTunes account. But iTunes said it was the fourth.

How do I find out what machines are authorized against my account?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go to iTunes on a computer and select your Account (on the right hand side of the window towards the top once you are signed in). Select Manage Devices under iTunes in the Cloud. All computers in this list count against the 5 total computer authorizations each Apple ID can have.

[image: Manage Devices]

- http://www.apple.com/legal/itunes/us/terms.html#SALE

Comment: Hmm. That list is completely wrong. It shows two Macs (should be three) -- neither of which are the new Mac I just added. An iPad and two iPhones. I thought iDevices didn't count, it was only computers. So as to where it's getting 4/5 from is still a mystery to me.

Comment: Open a ticket with [iTunes billing support](http://www.apple.com/support/itunes/account/) if the information is outdated or incorrect. They can and should reset things if your account doesn't match what iTunes lists. The once a year reset does complicate things since some older computers could be authorized against the "last 5 slots" and not the "current 5 slots".

Comment: My list is empty. But apparently I have authorized five devices already since Home Sharing cannot be activated on my Mac.

Comment: @bmike so Apple just reset all the authorized devices on my account for me and had me re-authorize the three Macs. I get the right "out of 5" count now but the list of devices under 'Manage Devices' only shows my iDevices, no Macs, now. Go figure.

Comment: @IanC. What you describe matches my experience with a reset. Any computers and devices continue to work and cen re-auorize yet no longer show or enumerate on a list of user machines.

Comment: @grgarside. The *Manage Devices* screen you are showing is for *associations* not *authorizations.* Confusing, I know, but Apple defines these similar terms very differently. See my answer for clarification and a working solution to the original question.

Comment: @GrowlTiger I simply added a screenshot to the answer following the instructions provided in the answer itself. Indeed, I had not noticed that the list showed associations rather than authorisations, but regardless, the screenshot that I added is of the page that the original answer referred to.

Comment: You cannot be associated without being authorized, so the latter is a subset of the former. Furthermore, this is the only list you can get from Apple to tell what computers are authorized by virtue of being both authorized+associated.

Comment: @bmike Your statement is only partially correct: A *computer* can only be associated if it is authorized. But authorization does not apply to iOS devices at all, even though they *can* be associated. More applicable to the original question, though, is that the *association* list need not contain *all* authorized devices. For example, I have 5 authorized computers, but only *three* devices in my *associated* list. So the associated list *may not necessarily* indicate the names of *all* of one's authorized computers.

Comment: @GrowlTiger 's explanation is the answer here.

Answer (score 55):

The question asks about computer *Authorization.* But some of the answers here confuse *Authorization* with *Association.* I'd like to clarify the terms first, using Apple's own definitions, then answer the question.

**Authorization**

> Authorization refers to *computers* only. *Authorizing* a computer allows you to play media purchased from the iTunes Store with a specific Apple ID. In order to use apps, audiobooks, books, DRM-protected music, and movies on a computer it must be *Authorized.* Each Apple ID can *authorize* a maximum of 5 *computers.*
>
> You can deauthorize each computer individually. If you've forgotten which computers you have authorized in the past, there is *not* a way to list all *authorized* computers. Apple only tells you the *number* that are authorized. However, once a year you can `Deauthorize All` computers from within your iTunes Store account settings.
>
> More information about *Authorization* can be found in this [Apple Tech Note.](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201251)

**Association**

> Association allows you to download past iTunes purchases onto a different *device.* Apple calls this *iTunes in the Cloud.* In addition, *association* allows the use of Apple features such as *iTunes Match* and *Automatic Downloads.*
>
> You can *associate* up to 10 *devices* with each Apple ID. By *device* Apple means an iOS gadget or an *authorized* computer. (Since every *associated* computer must also be *authorized* that limits you to 5 *associated* computers for these features.) So you can *associate* one computer and 9 other devices, or 5 computers and 5 other devices, but *not* 9 computers and 1 other device. You're limited to 5 *computers.*
>
> There *is* a list of *associated* devices which can be found in the *Account* section if iTunes Store.
>
> For more information on *Association* see this [Apple Tech Note](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204074)

**So the only way to determine which computers are *authorized* is by trial and error:** Deauthorize each computer you own in turn using `Store > Deauthorize This Computer…` within iTunes.

If after doing this the iTunes Store still says you have authorized computers, you only have one option: Use the `Deauthorize All` feature of iTunes Store, and then *reauthorize* the computers you own. But keep in mind, Apple only allows you to `Deauthorize All` once every twelve months.

**Special note about about Association and Android phones.**

Using Apple's own definition from the Support site.

You can't view a list of your associated devices or remove any of your associated devices using an Android phone, but **Android phones do count** against your ten-device limit.

More information about Authorization and Association can be found on the [View and remove your associated devices in iTunes](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204074) page.

Comment: This answer is correct while the chosen answer is not.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there is no way to see which specific computers are authorized; you can only see how many are authorized.

Per this Apple discussion thread, you will have to deauthorize all of them and reauthorize only the ones you want to be able to play.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3065517?start=0&tstart=0

I'm not sure if devices count toward this limit.

Answer (score 2):

the easiest way to do is
first deauthorize all accounts ,
then authorize all computer as you wish :)
according to https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204385#all

```
    Deauthorize all computers
================================

    If you need to deauthorize your computer but you can't access it, 
you need to deauthorize all computers. This option is available after you authorize 2 computers using your Apple ID. 
You can deauthorize all computers once per year.    
    You should deauthorize all computers if:    
    Your computer doesn't work anymore.
    You sold or gave away a computer and didn't deauthorize it first.
    To deauthorize all computers:    
    To automatically open iTunes and sign in to your Account Information page from your computer, 
click this link: View My Account. Or follow these steps:    
    Open iTunes.
    If you’re not signed in, sign in with your Apple ID.
    From the menu bar at the top of your computer screen or 
at the top of the iTunes window, choose Account > View My Account.
    Enter your password, then press the Return or Enter key on your keyboard, 
or click View Account.
    On the Account Information page:
    Scroll to the Apple ID Summary section. To the right of Computer Authorizations, click Deauthorize All.
    The Deauthorize All button appears only if you have more than 2 authorized computers. 
If you don't see the Deauthorize All button, that means that you only have one authorized computer.    
    When you deauthorize all, you don't lose content
    When you deauthorize a single computer, you don't lose content. The same applies to if you choose to deauthorize all computers. 
You just won't be able to access the content that you bought from iTunes on those computers 
until you reauthorize them. You need to have the computer to reauthorize it.



    After you deauthorize
==================================

    Reauthorize each computer that you want to use with iTunes:    
    Open iTunes.
    From the menu bar at the top of your computer screen or 
at the top of the iTunes window, 
choose Account > Authorizations > Authorize This Computer.
    Enter your Apple ID and password.
    Click Authorize.
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  We prefer you don't post link-only answers, even to an Apple site.  Links can change over time and then your answer would lose all relevance.  Please see [answer] for tips on providing good, complete answers.  - From Review

Comment: Thank you for point me Sir, I will try to post like you advise later.

Answer (score 2):

To see what computers are authorized you have to go to directly to the apple website (appleid.apple.com) and sign into your account. This is different from going to your account via the iTunes app itself.

On your account on the apple website, you will see all computers including Apple TV. When I did this, there were 2 authorized computers (that I had previously used) that showed up online but did not show up when I went through my iTunes app account.
[image: Devices seen on appleid.apple.com]
[image: Devices seen via iTunes app]

Comment: I see the exact same list of authorized devices in this web view as I do in iTunes. But this is definitely a prettier view of the authorized devices.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to do it on **macOS Catalina**.

Open **Music** application, go to menu `Account -> View my account`, under the `iTunes in the cloud` section click `Manage devices`, from here you can remove old devices that you authorised earlier.